# Maximum Combobox items in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I need to have a combobox that can have a large number of items (around 700), but there seems to be a limitation on how many items a combobox can contain (100!). Is there a way that this limitation can be extended?

**UPDATE:**

I cant really explain the scope here, but a search box would not be appropriate.

If MaxDropDownItems is set to 10 with 20 items, it provides a scroll bar to access the other 10, but is it not clear what will happen if 100 items is exceeded.

Unfortunately, it is not as simple as shoving over 100 items in there as it is populated based on a database. However, thankfully, we have a testing team!

I will post results of testing in due course.

Comment: what is this combobox going to be used for?  I think 700 items is a little excessive for users to scroll through.

Comment: I agree, but it is a requirement, the box is in fact a user control called CheckedComboBox, so any number of the items can be selected. In most cases there will not be 700, but there is a need to support this

Comment: It is quite simple to test by filling your comboBox with foo values: `for (int i = 0; i <= 150; i++) { 
comboBox.Items.Add(i.ToString()); 
}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ComboBox` can easily contain thousands of items. The 100 limit you are referring to is the visible portion which is displayed when the `ComboBox` drop down appears.

Note that the performance is tied to what type of data is being populated within the `ComboBox`; a complex object versus a simple string value. Virtualization of items does not exist with WinForms as it does in WPF/SL.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by GvS the [MaxDropDownItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.maxdropdownitems.aspx) property is the maximum number of visible items when the drop down portion is displayed.

So displaying 700 items (although not great for your users) will be possible.

You could use the [AutoCompleteMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode.aspx) property like below to enable filtering:

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    string item = string.Format("Item {0}", i.ToString());
    collection.Add(item);
    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
}

comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;
```

Comment: That property only allows a maximum of 100, I need it to be closer to 1000!

Comment: This property is about the number of items shown (before it starts scrolling), it does not set the maximum number of items in the list.

Comment: Interesting, never seen the AutoCompleteMode property, but text entry is not supported

Answer (score 1):

The UI of a combobox is not designed to let the user select from a list of 1000 elements. I personally think 20 items in a combobox is already too much. But if you want to add 700 items, there are no technical limitations.

Your users will be happier if you choose something that will make it easier to select an item. (Hint: something with a search box).